# Trying to stack an <aside> right next to an image

Tags: html, css

So I have an Article tag which basically consists of a hyper link, an image, a button and an aside.

The image is render the image inline and have the aside stacked right next to it. To be able to do this, this is what I am doing:

```
<article class = "friends_for_job"> 
  <header><a href = "\">Title</a></header>
  <img src = "*.jpg"></img>
  <aside>
     <p> info info info </p>
     <p> info info info </p>
   </aside>
   <input type = "button" value = "share">
</article>
```

The css for the above is:

```
.friend_for_job img{
display:block 
}
.friend_for_job aside{
display:inline;
}
```

Now this has the desired effect on my img, stacking it inline, but no such effect on the aside tag, and it gets rendered below the HTML tag.

Comment: The `img` element is a void element and [must not have an end tag](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#void-elements).

Comment: It probably doesn't (which is why it's a comment and not an answer), but you should still write valid HTML because invalid HTML may cause all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're aiming for?

```
.friends_for_job img { float:left; }
.friends_for_job aside { display:block; }
```

...adding margin and padding to taste.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo: Your class is named "**friend_for_job**", but you use "**friendS_for_job**". And than you can simply use this:

```
<style>
.friends_for_job img {
    float:  left; 
}
.friends_for_job aside {
    float:left;
}
</style>

<article class="friends_for_job"> 
  <header>
    <a href="">Title</a>
  </header>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-7.jpg" alt="">
  <aside>
     <p> info info info </p>
     <p> info info info </p>
   </aside>
   <input type = "button" value = "share">
</article>
```

Comment: the typo was because this is not an exact copy, it is fine in the code. thanks for the code, but this gets everything jumbled up, the hyperlink and the button render themselves inappropriately, whereas previously there positioning was great

Comment: So, the title stays on top, as before. Everything else floats next to the image. If you don't want the `input` to float, add a **clearfix** and it will be under the image again. Or is it something else, you want to achieve?